# How to handle scenario when application is resumed after long suspension (Without terminated)

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

My application displays data that it retrieves from a web-service. Let's say my application goes in suspended mode and remain suspended for long period of time. After that, when this application get resumed, I want to query the web-service again and display more up to date data in application. Problem is I am not sure what will be good place to handle this scenario. I have simplified version of code below. In the example below, I get resume in console windows when I use Suspend and Terminate option but when I only do a Suspend and after that Resume, no function seem to be called. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
app.addEventListener("resuming", function (vt) {
        console.log("resuming");
    });

    app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {
        console.log("activated");
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                console.log("new launch");
            } else {
                console.log("resume");
            }
        }
    });

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        console.log("suspended");
    };
```

Comment: how long are you waiting after the suspend to do the resume in the simulator?  the suspend does not happen immediately.

Comment: quite long, more than 30 second. oncheckpoint is called, so suspend is working. Question is about resume after suspend.

Comment: @Paul: I observed the same thing for a c# app. The way I worked around it was by checking for the visibility of main control. When it gets visible after suspend, i assumed it to be a resume. For your use case you could check your webservice periodically, instead on specific events.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your definition of the variable "app" is the standard from sample apps:

```
    var app = WinJS.Application;
```

then you cannot use that variable for "resuming" or "suspending" events, per [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229799.aspx) that reads:

> Note  Listeners for some Windows Store app events, like "suspending" and "resuming", cannot be added with this function. You must use Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener instead.

So instead, as that doc says, you need to use:

```
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("suspending", suspending, false);
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("resuming", resuming, false);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in your `function resuming(args)` you need to verify the type of event. Because `"resuming"` event seems to be fired upon app starting before `app.onactivated()` is called. So `function resuming(args){ if ( args.type === "resuming" ) { console.log("we are really resuming"); } else { console.log("We received non-resuming event of type: " + args.type ); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("resuming", function onresuming()
{
    Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog('hi i a resuming').showAsync();
});
```

refer msdn page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229799.aspx). Unfortunately `app.addEventListner('resuming', function() {})` is not throwing.

app resume section in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) msdn page also might be useful which talks about the same scenario of late resume.